# Update databricks job status through API

Tags: databricks

We need to execute a long running exe running on a windows machine and thinking of ways to integrate with the workflow. The plan is to include the exe as a task in the Databricks workflow.

We are thinking of couple of approaches

1. Create a DB table and enter a row when this particular task gets started in the workflow. Exe which is running on a windows machine will ping the database table for any new records. Once a new record is found, the exe proceeds with actual execution and updates the status after completion. Databricks will query this table constantly for the status and once completed, task finishes.
2. Using databricks API, check whether the task has started execution in the exe and continue with execution. After application finishes, update the task status to completion until then the Databricks task will run like while (true). But the current API doesn't support updating the task execution status (To Complete) (not 100% sure).

Please share thoughts OR alternate solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting problem. Is there a reason you must use Databricks to execute an EXE?

Regardless, I think you have the right kind of idea. How I would do this with the jobs api is as described:

1. Have your EXE process output a file to a staging location probably in DBFS since this will be locally accessible inside of databricks.
2. Build a notebook to load this file, having a table is optional but may give you addtional logging capabilities if needed. The output of your notebook should use the [dbutils.notebook.exit](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/notebook-workflows#:%7E:text=exit%20%28value%3A%20String%29%3A%20void%20Exit%20a%20notebook%20with,cause%20the%20job%20to%20fail%2C%20throw%20an%20exception.) method which allows you to output any value string or array. You could return "In Progress" and "Success" or the latest line from your file you've written.
3. [Wrap that notebook in a databricks job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/2.0/jobs#--create) and execute on an interval with a cron schedule (you said 1 minute) and you can retrieve the output value of your job via the [get-output endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/2.0/jobs#--runs-get-output)

Additional Note, the benefit of abstracting this into return values from a notebook is you could orchestrate this via other workflow tools e.g. Databricks Workflows or Azure Data Factory with inside an Until condition. There are no limits so long as you can orchestrate a notebook in that tool.

Comment: Thank you so much. Right now, this process is manually run by the user. There are many steps in the process that are migrated into databricks except exe. Otherwise they need to just execute the exe manually and rest in databricks which is not ideal.

Comment: Sorry if I am not clear. Exe application is running on windows machine and this needs to included as a task in databricks workflow. Once workflow is started, notebook task acts as a file watcher for a DBFS location. And windows exe which runs every minute will check the task status via jobs api as running and starts the execution and outputs the file in the DBFS. Is my understanding correct.

Comment: I've also edited my question for more clarity.